# how to get the text of first td of first row in datatable on load

Tags: datatable

I have a table which is created by plugins datatable that is coming from external json,Just I need to get the text of first TD of first TR on page load, It is working fine with static data but with external json its not working.I have already tried but its not working.
Can anyone please help me.Below is my code.Thanks in advance.

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="script.js"></script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-12">
</div>
<div id="div">
<div>
 <table id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>            
                <th>name</th>
                <th>stargazerscount</th>
                <th>forkscount</th>
                <th>description</th>               
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>          
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>  
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

### Javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable( {
language: {
        searchPlaceholder: "Search records"
    },
 "ajax": {
             "type"   : "POST",
            "url": "http://localhost/members.json",
             "dataSrc": function (json) {
      var return_data = new Array();
      for(var i=0;i< json.length; i++){

        return_data.push({

         'name': json[i].name,
          'stargazerscount'  : '<span onclick="f()">'+json[i].stargazerscount+'</span>',
           'forkscount'  : json[i].forkscount,
          'description' : json[i].description
        })

      }

      return return_data;
             }
    },

        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "stargazerscount" },
            { "data": "forkscount" },
            { "data": "description" }

        ]

}); 
  var x = $('#example tbody tr:first').find('td:first').text();
alert(x);    
}
);
```

### members.json

```
[{
            "name": "mango",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "fruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "brinjal",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "vagetables"
        },
        {
            "name": "grapes",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "fruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "soap",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "groceries"
        },
        {
            "name": "dates",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "dryfruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
        {
            "name": "shirt",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "clothes"
        },
        {
            "name": "dates",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "dryfruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
        {
            "name": "shirt",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "clothes"
        },
        {
            "name": "shirt",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "clothes"
        },
        {
            "name": "dates",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "dryfruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
        {
            "name": "shirt",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "clothes"
        },
        {
            "name": "dates",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "dryfruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
         {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        }


    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign a variable to your datatable declaration. Like `var dtable` in:

```
var dtable = $('#example').DataTable({
```

Inside your declaration add `initComplete` property so your needed code is successfully executed because your datatables is already fully loaded.

```
"initComplete": function(settings, json) {
    var column = dtable .row(0).data();
      alert(column[0]);
    },
```

**Updated Code:**

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
  var dtable = $('#example').DataTable({
    language: {
      searchPlaceholder: "Search records"
    },
    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
    var column = dtable.row(0).data();
      alert(column[0]);
    },
    "ajax": {
      "type": "POST",
      "url": "http://localhost/members.json",
      "dataSrc": function(json) {
        var return_data = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

          return_data.push({

            'name': json[i].name,
            'stargazerscount': '<span onclick="f()">' + json[i].stargazerscount + '</span>',
            'forkscount': json[i].forkscount,
            'description': json[i].description
          })

        }

        return return_data;
      }
    },

    "columns": [{
        "data": "name"
      },
      {
        "data": "stargazerscount"
      },
      {
        "data": "forkscount"
      },
      {
        "data": "description"
      }

    ]

  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: let value = dtable.row( i ).data()[ j ]; worked for me with i = table line & j table col

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select first instance of td (basically first tr's first td) by vanilla:

```
document.querySelector('td').innerHTML;
```

Only problem is that DOM is not updated yet when you are trying to select that element.

To avoid that, put it into initComplete:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    language: {
        searchPlaceholder: "Search records"
    },
    "ajax": {
        "type"   : "POST",
        "url": "http://localhost/members.json",
        "dataSrc": function (json) {
            var return_data = new Array();
            for(var i=0;i< json.length; i++){

                return_data.push({
                    $('#example').DataTable( {
                    language: {
                        searchPlaceholder: "Search records"
                    },
                    "ajax": {
                        "type"   : "POST",
                        "url": "http://localhost/members.json",
                        "dataSrc": function (json) {
                            var return_data = new Array();
                            for(var i=0;i< json.length; i++){

                                return_data.push({

                                    'name': json[i].name,
                                    'stargazerscount'  : '<span onclick="f()">'+json[i].stargazerscount+'</span>',
                                    'forkscount'  : json[i].forkscount,
                                    'description' : json[i].description
                                })

                            }

                            return return_data;
                        }
                    },

                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "name" },
                        { "data": "stargazerscount" },
                        { "data": "forkscount" },
                        { "data": "description" }

                    ]

                });
                'name': json[i].name,
                    'stargazerscount'  : '<span onclick="f()">'+json[i].stargazerscount+'</span>',
                    'forkscount'  : json[i].forkscount,
                    'description' : json[i].description
                })

            }

            return return_data;
        }
    },

    "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "stargazerscount" },
        { "data": "forkscount" },
        { "data": "description" }

    ],

    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        console.log(document.querySelector('td').innerHTML);
    }
});
```

This will wait for it to init and then execute the script.
More info can be found [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete).

Comment: Thanks for your help,actually I want to pass this console value into variable and call outside the datatable to use it.I tried but its not showing that value